# What is the purpose of the text value in-between <progress> tags?

Tags: html, syntax

I am learning about the progress bar tag provided in HTML5. In examples on the Mozilla and W3C websites they have something like this:

```html
<label for="file">File progress:</label>
<progress id="file" max="100" value="70"> 70% </progress>
```

With a value (e.g. '70%' in the above) between the tags. However, when I remove this number between the tags, it makes no difference to the visual output when I display it in the browser. Neither website explains what the purpose of this number is. They only explain the 'value' attribute which appears to be the number that determines the actually progress shown, rather than the number between the tags.

To clarify, I think I understand the 'value' attribute in the opening tag, but why is this information duplicated (apparently unnecessarily) between the tags?

Is the number between the tags important? What is it for?

Comment: Phrasing content: [Terminology](https://w3c.github.io/html-reference/terminology.html#phrasing-content)

[Content model](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#phrasing-content-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's there for non-visual browsers such as screen readers. Obviously the phrase must be updated by something to keep the text current with relation to the visual progress bar.

Comment: Interesting thanks. So screen readers are unable to pickup the 'value' attribute directly from the object?